# Updating tlmgr 2011 to 2012

Tags: texlive

When I run

```
# tlmgr update --self
```

This is the reply I get:

```
tlmgr: package repository ftp://ftp.riken.go.jp/pub/tex-archive/systems/texlive/tlnet
/usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr: The TeX Live versions supported by the repository
(2012--2012)
do not include the version of the local installation
(2011).  Goodbye.
```

Could anyone guide me on how to update tlmgr to 2012? Do I have to uninstall and install TeX Live all over again?

Thanks in advance

Update: I use Scientific Linux

Comment: See: http://www.tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html - But you can install TL 2012 next to TL 2011

Comment: Thanks, but won't this take too much disk space? LaTeX has already taken ~2Gbytes on my computer!

Comment: @astroboy Depends on your situation. I have a 250 Gb disk in my laptop, which is in total less than a quarter full despite having MacTeX 2011, MacTeX 2012, TL2011 (Win), TL2012 (Win) and TL2011 (Ubuntu) installed :-)

Comment: You can install TL 2012 and remove the old folder 2011. That's all

Comment: Thanks a lot Marco and Joseph. Actually my computer has 2 TeraBytes of space and most of it is empty but I want to be efficient. So I will remove and install the whole new thing when ever I have some free time. Thanks again.

Comment: @astroboy: there's efficient of computer resources and efficient of your time.  back when i had 100 k_words_ disc space allocation (1969), there was no choice.  with 2tbyte to play with, you can surely not worry! -- on my work desktop, with rather smaller disc, i've got three annual copies of tl.  not particularly because i _need_ them, but because it has saved thinking time!

Comment: See [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/64757/8528), which points to [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/163683/31420) on 'ask Ubuntu'.  Apparently you can install TL 2012 from an official backport now.

Comment: @wasteofspace: You are right, I don't disagree. I believe it is a matter of taste and personal preference. My need for the new `tlmgr` was not urgent so I could afford to wait for some free time to just remove the whole old version and install a new one (infact I am looking forward to reinstall my whole OS and update everything!). If it was urgent I would surely do as you have done. I like to be in control of what I install even though I am not using more than 8/10s of my desktop hard disk space now!

Comment: @jon: Thank you I will have a look. But I use Scientific Linux. So I don't know how much that applies to my system. I will check it out.

Comment: Right, well that sounds like a Red Hat question then.  I like to stay in the Debian world.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Transform your comment into a true answer then I will delete my answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [document](http://www.tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html) describes how to upgrade from TeXLive 2011 to TeXLive 2012.

Comment: Marco Daniel provided the link in his comment from Jul 22.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen Sorry. I had not carefully read all the comments.

Comment: No need to apologise.....