# Updating pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, packages, mactex

I am using LaTeX in MacOsx Lion. My current version of `pgfplots` is 1.4.1 which I want to upgrade to 1.7. I really do not know how to install version 1.7. Any help?

Comment: I've retagged with MacTeX assuming that's the one you use. Can you please include all other details about your distribution?

Comment: have you seen [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437)

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are employing the latest TeXlive (MacTeX is built on TeXlive, right?) or similar (MikTeX on windows) it is just a matter of updating with the update tools supplied (see @Pouya answer about TeX-live). However, it could be argued that you needed a more general, *switchable* solution.

Here is what I do:

I generate some local folder which is named `out-of-live/tex`. Within that folder you can put a regular [TDS](http://ctan.open-source-solution.org/tds/tds.html) structure to comply with regular TeX installations.

In there I put `pgfplots` and (also `pgf` as that is typically required to be the lastest [CVS](http://sourceforge.net/scm/?type=cvs&group_id=142562&source=navbar) version as well).

So I do a local installation of those packages, and others if I like, just there. In general I use `CVS` and `git` to be able to update them to the newest state, at any time (thereby going past the `TeX`-distribution).

Then the folder structure becomes:

```
.../out-of-live/tex/  
                    pgf/
                    pgfplots/
```

Now, you simply need to edit your `texmf.cnf` file to add this `out-of-live` to the search path for sources.
Locate your file by: `kpsewhich texmf.cnf`.
Then edit that file and find the line referring to `TEXMFHOME`.

Then do this:

```
TEXMFHOME = {../out-of-live}
% or if it already contains ~/texmf do
TEXMFHOME = {~/texmf,../out-of-live}
```

TeXlive will automatically assume that that folder contains a TDS compliant directory structure, hence it will look for sources in `tex`, documentations in `doc`, etc.
Remember that `TEXMFHOME` will be searched before the regular installation path.

Also note, that typically by default, `TeXlive` adds the folder `~/texmf` to the search path as well (so you could just place folders `pgf` and `pgfplots` in `~/texmf/tex`, but the above is a more general picture).

Answer (score 3):

Mac distribution of LaTeX comes with a little GUI tool called `Tex Live Utility` that allows you to upgrade packages. You can find it in your Application folder side by side tex editors. Another method is to use terminal command `tlmgr` in this fashion:

```
tlmgr update <packagename>
```

or for updating everything:

```
tlmgr update --all
```

To use `tlmgr` you might need `sudo` access.

#### Edit:

Probably you will be prompted to update `tlmgr` itself. To do so, try

```
tlmgr update --self
```

Comment: Pouya, thank you for your help. I tried (tlmgr update --all) but the message came as follows :                     pt-sd444:~ subhankardasbakshi$ tlmgr update --list
tlmgr: package repository http://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet
/usr/texbin/tlmgr: The TeX Live versions supported by the repository
  (2012--2012)
do not include the version of the local installation
  (2011).  Goodbye.

Comment: @subhankar, Did you try also with the GUI software? I'm sorry but my latex is up to date so I can't really study this error! Btw I think you have three solutions. 1. To install the latest version of MacTex side-by-side the version that you are using now (or remove the old one and install the latest). 2. Follow the instructions of [this](http://www.tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html) link and/or [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64261/updating-tlmgr-2011-to-2012) question. And thirdly, try the solution proposed by zeroth.