# Plot doesn't care about axis setting

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have a Pgfplot and for some reason it does not care about my y-axis settings... I have set ymax to 15 but for some reason it only goes up to ymax is 14 or something...

Can anyone explain why? And how I fix this?

Since my plot is based on coordinate data (and the complete source) exceeds the input limit of a question you can download the complete source here: http://pastebin.com/nwNwuFam

However I also noticed that this also occures when I don't set any coordinate data...

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotsset{plot coordinates/math parser=false}

\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}

\pgfplotsset{%
  width=4cm,
  height=4cm,
  scale only axis,
  every x tick label/.append style={font=\scriptsize\color{gray!80!black}},
  xmajorgrids,
  xminorgrids,
  every y tick label/.append style={font=\scriptsize\color{gray!80!black}},
  ymajorgrids,
  yminorgrids
}

\begin{axis}[%
xmin=0, xmax=0.015,
xlabel={Time [\si{\second}]},
ymin=-10, ymax=15,
ylabel={$x_i$},
scaled x ticks=base 10:2]

\addplot [
color=blue,
solid
]
coordinates{};

\addplot [
color=green!50!black,
solid
]
coordinates{};

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The plot goes up to 15 for me, and none of the data is cut off. What version of PGFPlots are you using?

Comment: How can I check that?

Comment: It's printed in your `.log` file that's generated when you compile your document, somewhere near the start of the file.

Comment: Hmmmm so I guess I use... `Package: pgfplots 2011/12/29 v1.5.1 (git show 1.5.1-4-g53e640f )` then? http://pastebin.com/nSg5L7UG

Which I guess is not the latest version... You got any tips how to update pgfplots fast? I don't want to reinstall texlive namely all over again and I can't use tlgmr :(

Comment: Yeah, updating PGFPlots might be a good idea. Take a look at the second answer to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97743/updating-pgfplots for a way of doing this without `tlmgr`

Comment: @Jake Hmmmm thanks but I think this will take to long for me anyway... Could you maybe do me a favor and compile the code in pastebin? And upload the .pdf? Only this plot goes wrong namely others work perfectly fine.

Comment: Sure, here you go: http://ge.tt/5UVPvOe/v/0?c

Comment: Thanks! Small question did you smoothen the plot or something? The plot looks a lot smoother then when I compile it, mine is more pixely so to speak. Proberbly because you use a newer version of pgfplots or other tex distribution... but just in case I ask anyway.

Comment: Pleasure. No, I didn't change your code at all.