# Using the latest version of pgfplots installed

Tags: pgfplots

I want to use the latest pgfplots, in this case v1.18, but apparently, only v1.15 is used judging from the log file as

```
) (pgfplots.sty (pgfplots.revision.tex)
Package: pgfplots 2017/06/05 v1.15 Data Visualization (1.15)
```

Referring to [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97743/updating-pgfplots), I tried editing one statement in `/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf.cnf` as

```
TEXMFHOME = ~/Library/texmf, /Users/(my name)/Downloads/pgfplots 
% ^ /Users/... has been added, which is where pgfplots 1.18 exists at the moment.
```

However, the log file was still the same. I also tried

```
$ sudo tlmgr update pgfplots
Password:
tlmgr: package repository https://ftp.yz.yamagata-u.ac.jp/pub/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet (verified)
tlmgr: saving backups to /usr/local/texlive/2023/tlpkg/backups
tlmgr: no updates available
```

which, as the message suggests, made no diffrence.

What can I do to use v1.18? One possibility is that v1.18 is not correctly installed, but I don't know how to.

My environment is

```
$ latex --version
pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023)
kpathsea version 6.3.5
Copyright 2023 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
Compiled with libpng 1.6.39; using libpng 1.6.39
Compiled with zlib 1.2.13; using zlib 1.2.13
Compiled with xpdf version 4.04
```

**Update 1**

I am using Mac OS, and I've got the following output in response the comment. And I am aware that these are the directories of v1.15, notv1.18.

```
$ kpsewhich pgfplots.sty
/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgfplots/pgfplots.sty
$ kpsewhich pgfplots.revision.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplots.revision.tex
```

pgfplots.sty exists in two directories.

**Update 2**

The log I get from `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{pgfplots} \begin{document} \end{document}` is as follows.

```
This is TexpadTeX (based on TeX Version 3.14159265 with e-TeX extensions) running in extended mode embedded in Texpad 760 (preloaded format=latex 2021.3.29)  2 JUN 2023 16:28
**
(root.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.16> and hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.
(article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
) (pgfplots.sty (pgfplots.revision.tex)
Package: pgfplots 2017/06/05 v1.15 Data Visualization (1.15)
(graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2017/06/01 v1.1a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
(keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks14
) (graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2017/06/25 v1.2c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
(trig.sty
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
) (graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2018/05/3 Graphics configuration of TexpadTeX
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: texpadtex.def on input line 99.
(texpadtex.def
File: texpadtex.def 2017/10/21 v2.0
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen103
\Gin@req@width=\dimen104
) (tikz.sty (pgf.sty (pgfrcs.sty (pgfutil-common.tex
\pgfutil@everybye=\toks15
\pgfutil@tempdima=\dimen105
\pgfutil@tempdimb=\dimen106
(pgfutil-common-lists.tex)) (pgfutil-latex.def
\pgfutil@abb=\box26
(everyshi.sty
Package: everyshi 2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
)) (pgfrcs.code.tex
Package: pgfrcs 2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.31)
))
Package: pgf 2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.15)
(pgfcore.sty (pgfsys.sty (pgfsys.code.tex
Package: pgfsys 2014/07/09 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.48)
(pgfkeys.code.tex
\pgfkeys@pathtoks=\toks16
\pgfkeys@temptoks=\toks17
(pgfkeysfiltered.code.tex
\pgfkeys@tmptoks=\toks18
))
\pgf@x=\dimen107
\pgf@y=\dimen108
\pgf@xa=\dimen109
\pgf@ya=\dimen110
\pgf@xb=\dimen111
\pgf@yb=\dimen112
\pgf@xc=\dimen113
\pgf@yc=\dimen114
\w@pgf@writea=\write3
\r@pgf@reada=\read1
\c@pgf@counta=\count87
\c@pgf@countb=\count88
\c@pgf@countc=\count89
\c@pgf@countd=\count90
\t@pgf@toka=\toks19
\t@pgf@tokb=\toks20
\t@pgf@tokc=\toks21
(pgf.cfg
File: pgf.cfg 2008/05/14  (rcs-revision 1.7)
)
Driver file for pgf: pgfsys-texpadtex.def
(pgfsys-texpadtex.def)) (pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex
File: pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex 2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
\pgfsyssoftpath@smallbuffer@items=\count91
\pgfsyssoftpath@bigbuffer@items=\count92
) (pgfsysprotocol.code.tex
File: pgfsysprotocol.code.tex 2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
)) (xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
(color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2018/05/3 Graphics configuration of TexpadTeX
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: texpadtex.def on input line 225.
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1348.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1364.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1366.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1367.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1368.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1369.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1370.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1371.
) (pgfcore.code.tex
Package: pgfcore 2010/04/11 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)
(pgfmath.code.tex (pgfmathcalc.code.tex (pgfmathutil.code.tex) (pgfmathparser.code.tex
\pgfmath@dimen=\dimen115
\pgfmath@count=\count93
\pgfmath@box=\box27
\pgfmath@toks=\toks22
\pgfmath@stack@operand=\toks23
\pgfmath@stack@operation=\toks24
) (pgfmathfunctions.code.tex (pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.tex) (pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric.code.tex) (pgfmathfunctions.random.code.tex) (pgfmathfunctions.comparison.code.tex) (pgfmathfunctions.base.code.tex) (pgfmathfunctions.round.code.tex) (pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.tex) (pgfmathfunctions.integerarithmetics.code.tex))) (pgfmathfloat.code.tex
\c@pgfmathroundto@lastzeros=\count94
)) (pgfcorepoints.code.tex
File: pgfcorepoints.code.tex 2013/10/07  (rcs-revision 1.27)
\pgf@picminx=\dimen116
\pgf@picmaxx=\dimen117
\pgf@picminy=\dimen118
\pgf@picmaxy=\dimen119
\pgf@pathminx=\dimen120
\pgf@pathmaxx=\dimen121
\pgf@pathminy=\dimen122
\pgf@pathmaxy=\dimen123
\pgf@xx=\dimen124
\pgf@xy=\dimen125
\pgf@yx=\dimen126
\pgf@yy=\dimen127
\pgf@zx=\dimen128
\pgf@zy=\dimen129
) (pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex 2013/10/07  (rcs-revision 1.29)
\pgf@path@lastx=\dimen130
\pgf@path@lasty=\dimen131
) (pgfcorepathusage.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathusage.code.tex 2014/11/02  (rcs-revision 1.24)
\pgf@shorten@end@additional=\dimen132
\pgf@shorten@start@additional=\dimen133
) (pgfcorescopes.code.tex
File: pgfcorescopes.code.tex 2015/05/08  (rcs-revision 1.46)
\pgfpic=\box28
\pgf@hbox=\box29
\pgf@layerbox@main=\box30
\pgf@picture@serial@count=\count95
) (pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex
File: pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex 2014/11/02  (rcs-revision 1.12)
\pgflinewidth=\dimen134
) (pgfcoretransformations.code.tex
File: pgfcoretransformations.code.tex 2015/08/07  (rcs-revision 1.20)
\pgf@pt@x=\dimen135
\pgf@pt@y=\dimen136
\pgf@pt@temp=\dimen137
) (pgfcorequick.code.tex
File: pgfcorequick.code.tex 2008/10/09  (rcs-revision 1.3)
) (pgfcoreobjects.code.tex
File: pgfcoreobjects.code.tex 2006/10/11  (rcs-revision 1.2)
) (pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex 2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
) (pgfcorearrows.code.tex
File: pgfcorearrows.code.tex 2015/05/14  (rcs-revision 1.43)
\pgfarrowsep=\dimen138
) (pgfcoreshade.code.tex
File: pgfcoreshade.code.tex 2013/07/15  (rcs-revision 1.15)
\pgf@max=\dimen139
\pgf@sys@shading@range@num=\count96
) (pgfcoreimage.code.tex
File: pgfcoreimage.code.tex 2013/07/15  (rcs-revision 1.18)
(pgfcoreexternal.code.tex
File: pgfcoreexternal.code.tex 2014/07/09  (rcs-revision 1.21)
\pgfexternal@startupbox=\box31
)) (pgfcorelayers.code.tex
File: pgfcorelayers.code.tex 2013/07/18  (rcs-revision 1.7)
) (pgfcoretransparency.code.tex
File: pgfcoretransparency.code.tex 2013/09/30  (rcs-revision 1.5)
) (pgfcorepatterns.code.tex
File: pgfcorepatterns.code.tex 2013/11/07  (rcs-revision 1.5)
))) (pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex
File: pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex 2014/03/21  (rcs-revision 1.35)
\pgfnodeparttextbox=\box32
) (pgfmoduleplot.code.tex
File: pgfmoduleplot.code.tex 2015/08/03  (rcs-revision 1.13)
) (pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty
Package: pgfcomp-version-0-65 2007/07/03 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)
\pgf@nodesepstart=\dimen140
\pgf@nodesepend=\dimen141
) (pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty
Package: pgfcomp-version-1-18 2007/07/23 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.1)
)) (pgffor.sty (pgfkeys.sty (pgfkeys.code.tex)) (pgfmath.sty (pgfmath.code.tex)) (pgffor.code.tex
Package: pgffor 2013/12/13 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.25)
(pgfmath.code.tex)
\pgffor@iter=\dimen142
\pgffor@skip=\dimen143
\pgffor@stack=\toks25
\pgffor@toks=\toks26
)) (tikz.code.tex
Package: tikz 2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.151)
(pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex
File: pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex 2013/08/31 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.20)
\pgf@plot@mark@count=\count97
\pgfplotmarksize=\dimen144
)
\tikz@lastx=\dimen145
\tikz@lasty=\dimen146
\tikz@lastxsaved=\dimen147
\tikz@lastysaved=\dimen148
\tikzleveldistance=\dimen149
\tikzsiblingdistance=\dimen150
\tikz@figbox=\box33
\tikz@figbox@bg=\box34
\tikz@tempbox=\box35
\tikz@tempbox@bg=\box36
\tikztreelevel=\count98
\tikznumberofchildren=\count99
\tikznumberofcurrentchild=\count100
\tikz@fig@count=\count101
(pgfmodulematrix.code.tex
File: pgfmodulematrix.code.tex 2013/09/17  (rcs-revision 1.8)
\pgfmatrixcurrentrow=\count102
\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn=\count103
\pgf@matrix@numberofcolumns=\count104
)
\tikz@expandcount=\count105
(tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex
File: tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex 2008/06/17 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.2)
))) (pgfplots.code.tex (pgfplotscore.code.tex
\t@pgfplots@toka=\toks27
\t@pgfplots@tokb=\toks28
\t@pgfplots@tokc=\toks29
\pgfplots@tmpa=\dimen151
\c@pgfplots@coordindex=\count106
\c@pgfplots@scanlineindex=\count107
(pgfplotssysgeneric.code.tex)) (pgfplotslibrary.code.tex) (pgfplotsoldpgfsupp_loader.code.tex (pgflibraryfpu.code.tex)
Package pgfplots: loading complementary arithmetics for your pgf version...
(pgfplotsoldpgfsupp_pgflibraryfpu.code.tex) (pgfplotsoldpgfsupp_pgfmathfloat.code.tex
\c@pgfmathroundto@lastzeros=\count108
)) (pgfplotsutil.code.tex (pgfplotsliststructure.code.tex) (pgfplotsliststructureext.code.tex) (pgfplotsarray.code.tex
\c@pgfplotsarray@tmp=\count109
) (pgfplotsmatrix.code.tex) (pgfplotstableshared.code.tex
\c@pgfplotstable@counta=\count110
\t@pgfplotstable@a=\toks30
) (pgfplotsdeque.code.tex) (pgfplotsbinary.code.tex (pgfplotsbinary.data.code.tex)) (pgfplotsutil.verb.code.tex) (pgflibrarypgfplots.surfshading.code.tex
\c@pgfplotslibrarysurf@no=\count111
)) (pgfplotscolormap.code.tex (pgfplotscolor.code.tex)) (pgfplotsstackedplots.code.tex) (pgfplotsplothandlers.code.tex (pgfplotsmeshplothandler.code.tex (pgfplotsmeshplotimage.code.tex))) (pgfplots.scaling.code.tex) (pgfplotscoordprocessing.code.tex) (pgfplots.errorbars.code.tex) (pgfplots.markers.code.tex) (pgfplotsticks.code.tex) (pgfplots.paths.code.tex) (tikzlibrarydecorations.code.tex (pgfmoduledecorations.code.tex
\pgfdecoratedcompleteddistance=\dimen152
\pgfdecoratedremainingdistance=\dimen153
\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentcompleteddistance=\dimen154
\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentremainingdistance=\dimen155
\pgf@decorate@distancetomove=\dimen156
\pgf@decorate@repeatstate=\count112
\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude=\dimen157
\pgfdecorationsegmentlength=\dimen158
)
\tikz@lib@dec@box=\box37
) (tikzlibrarydecorations.pathmorphing.code.tex (pgflibrarydecorations.pathmorphing.code.tex)) (tikzlibrarydecorations.pathreplacing.code.tex (pgflibrarydecorations.pathreplacing.code.tex))
\pgfplots@numplots=\count113
\pgfplots@xmin@reg=\dimen159
\pgfplots@xmax@reg=\dimen160
\pgfplots@ymin@reg=\dimen161
\pgfplots@ymax@reg=\dimen162
\pgfplots@zmin@reg=\dimen163
\pgfplots@zmax@reg=\dimen164
) (tikzlibraryplotmarks.code.tex
File: tikzlibraryplotmarks.code.tex 2008/01/09 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.1)
(pgflibraryplotmarks.code.tex
File: pgflibraryplotmarks.code.tex 2015/08/03 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.14)
))) (root.aux)
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 1.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 1.
ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros

Package pgfplots Warning: running in backwards compatibility mode (unsuitable tick labels; missing features). Consider writing \pgfplotsset{compat=1.15} into your preamble.
 on input line 1.

(root.aux) )
No pages of output.
```

Comment: Currently your question is quite unclear. Are you using MacOS (I'm asking because of having `~/Library` in TEXMFHOME and using `sudo`)? Are you using Windows (I'm asking because of using `/Users/(my name)` as path)? Which paths do `kpsewhich pgfplots.sty` and `kpsewhich pgfplots.revision.tex` show? Have you only `pgfplots.sty` in you extra directory or all files of `pgfplots`? However, it seems that your `/Users/(my name)/Downloads/pgfplots` is not a real TEXMF tree, as it has to be (see `texdoc kpathsea`) but only a single directory. Please add more information to the question.

Comment: Extra note: With TeX Live and Mac OSX or Linux/Unix `sudo tlmgr -update -all` or `sudo tlmgr update pgfplots` should indeed update `pgfplots` to the latest version (currently 1.18). Depending on the owner of `/usr/local/texlive/2023` you even would not need `sudo`. So if this does not work, you should use `kpsewhich` to get the location of the used `pdfplots`. Maybe you already have one installed in another location, that is found before the one of the TeX Live distribution.

Comment: texlive has `Package: pgfplots 2021/05/15 v1.18.1 Data Visualization (1.18.1)`  your log shows you have an old one  in your current directory which you should delete

Comment: @cabohah I have added the information. However, `sudo tlmgr update pgfplots` did not work as in my original post.

Comment: Have you run `kpsewhich pgfplots.sty` from within your document directory or another one? Because—as David wrote—it seems, that `pgfplots.sty` is used from the document directory, when you compile. But files in the document directory are only found (by `kpsewhich` or LaTeX), if the document directory is the current directory. Please, if there are files `pgfplots*`, rename them and try compiling again (after `sudo tlmgr install --reinstall pgfplots`).

Comment: `kpsewhich pgfplots.sty` from within my document directory resulted in `/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgfplots/pgfplots.sty`, which is the older ver. I renamed `/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgfplots/` and tried `sudo tlmgr install --reinstall pgfplots`, but had v1.15 installed, not v1.18.

Comment: You have installed texlive 2023 but you are not using it,you are using  a 6 year old  latex `LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>`  from `TexpadTeX` which is a different tex implementation

Answer (score 3):

Your log should show

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgfplots/pgfplots.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplots.revision.tex)
Package: pgfplots 2021/05/15 v1.18.1 Data Visualization (1.18.1)
```

getting 1.18.1 from texlive.

You show

```
) (pgfplots.sty (pgfplots.revision.tex)
Package: pgfplots 2017/06/05 v1.15 Data Visualization (1.15)
```

so you have an old copy in the current directory which you should delete to allow tex to find the updated installed copy.

---

Actually following the full log being added to the question,the reaso full paths are not shown in the log is that you are not using your installed texlive 2023 system.

You are using  a 6 year old  latex `LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>`  from `TexpadTeX` which is a different tex implementation

Comment: I tried removing `/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgfplots` and `/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/`, which are where `pgfplots.sty` and `pgfplots.revision.tex` are located respectively, to a completely irrelevant location(Desktop).
However, the result was still the same. v1.15 in the log file. I suspect the installation of v.1.18 is not properly done, but can't figure out how to.

Comment: no! never edit under  `/usr/local/texlive/2023` you just confuse the package manager and break tex. use tlmgr to force a re-instll of pgfplots!!!! @Kaz

Comment: Later, I restored the files/folders, so I assume it is okay.
As for tlmgr, could you tell me the command to use? As in my original post, `sudo tlmgr update pgfplots` didn't work.

Comment: @Kaz you have shown no input and only a  tiny fragment of log. Show the log you get from `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\end{document}`  in a code block in your question. Your fragment suggests it will show `article.cls` coming from `texlive` but `pgfplots .sty` coming from the local directory

Comment: I've added the log in the post.

Comment: @Kaz `This is TexpadTeX`  so not texlive at all. How many tex systems have you installed?